# Регулярное выражение: разбить адрес дома на составные части

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-maps-api, php

Передо мной встала задача разбить адрес дома на составные части (улица и дом). Сразу подумал про регулярные выражения, но в них я не очень силен. Прошу помочь...

Адреса могут быть в любом виде (т.е. как пользователь захочет так и вводит). Например:

- Невский пр., д.5
- невский проспект, дом 5
- ул. Ефимова, д 6
- улица ефимова, дом6
- 1-я линия В.О., д.1

Пробовал использовать google maps api, но при не полном адресе выводит странные результаты, например, при запросе "невск" в ответе приходит "ул. Колонтай"

Comment: Нельзя написать регулярное выражение на адрес в любом виде. Нужно ограничить кол-во вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя "чисто" из вашего примера можно упереться на запятую и сделать так:

```
list($street, $house) = explode(",", $str);
```

Ну а если необходимо что то большее, то самым оптимальным вариантом будет сделать в форме два инпута, один для улицы, другой для дома и тогда все проблемы отпадут.

Answer (score 0):

В одной из моих наработок ввод данных идёт в два этапа. На первом пользователь заполняет форму, на втором ему кроме формы с его данными предоставляется распознанный вариант для подтверждения. Если неправильно распарсило адрес (улица, дом) пользователь имеет возможность исправить строку согласно предложенным рекомендациям. По правилам хорошего тона под(возле) названия поля или самого поля предлагается вариант заполнения (ул. Такаято, д. 15)